# go: What is the n parameter in regexp:FindAll()

Tags: go

I use regexp.FindAll() to get all the matches. I don't understand the parameter of `n`, and in the [office reference](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAll), there is no explanation. How can I set the parameter.

```
// FindAll is the 'All' version of Find; it returns a slice of all successive
// matches of the expression, as defined by the 'All' description in the
// package comment.
// A return value of nil indicates no match.
func (re *Regexp) FindAll(b []byte, n int) [][]byte {}
```

Answer (score 6):

From https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/:

> Find(All)?(String)?(Submatch)?(Index)?
>
> If 'All' is present, the routine matches successive non-overlapping
>   matches of the entire expression. Empty matches abutting a preceding
>   match are ignored. The return value is a slice containing the
>   successive return values of the corresponding non-'All' routine. These
>   routines take an extra integer argument, n; if n >= 0, the function
>   returns at most n matches/submatches.